# UP2715H "stuck" at 3k resolution

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, high-resolution

I have got a **UP2715K** display from Dell and a **PNY Quadro M2000.**
Unluckily I'm not able to achieve a **5K** resolution on **Windows 10 Pro,** even if all the drivers are installed (and both the DP cables are connected).

---

I've already checked both the cables and both works fine.
Surfing the menus, I saw that in the **NVidia** control panel only one cable is detected, in the first DP connector.

---

So I did try to unplug the 2nd cable, and the computer didn't even notice it.
I did try to install other drivers version too but without success.
[NVidia control panel (sorry for the Italian language)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MWm9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem.
I searched for the "MST" keyword and found a post from a guy in the NVidia forum who said he unplugged the monitor for about 30 seconds and it worked for him.
I searched more on the net, with no success, so I did try to unplug the monitor for about 1 minute, plugged in and it worked :)